# Extending a namespace in an inline namespace that initially was defined in the enclosing namespace of the inline namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, definition, c++20

I would like to check myself whether I understand correctly the following quote below from the C++ 20 Standard (English is not my native language).

Section 9.7.1 Namespace definition:

> 2 In a named-namespace-definition, the identifier is the name of the
>   namespace. If the identifier, when looked up (6.4.1), refers to a
>   namespace-name (but not a namespace-alias) that was introduced in the
>   namespace in which the named-namespace-definition appears or that was
>   introduced in a member of the inline namespace set of that namespace,
>   the namespace-definition extends the previously-declared namespace.
>   Otherwise, the identifier is introduced as a namespace-name into the
>   declarative region in which the named-namespacedefinition appears.

That is may a namespace be defined in a namespace and then extended in one of its inline namespace? Or vice versa. May a namespace be defined in an inline namespace and then be extended in its enclosing namespace?

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace N1
{
    inline namespace N2
    {
        namespace N3
        {
            void f( int ) { std::cout << "f( int )\n"; }
        }
    }

    namespace N3
    {
        void f( char ) { std::cout << "f( char )\n"; }
    }        
}

int main()
{
    N3::f( 10 );
    N3::f( 'A' );
}
```

The program output is

```
f( int )
f( char )
```

However for this program the compiler issues an error saying that reference to 'N3' is ambiguous.

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace N1
{
    namespace N3
    {
        void f( int ) { std::cout << "f( int )\n"; }
    }

    inline namespace N2
    {
        namespace N3
        {
            void f( char ) { std::cout << "f( char )\n"; }
        }        
    }
}

int main()
{
    N3::f( 10 );
    N3::f( 'A' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> may a namespace be defined in a namespace and then extended in one of its inline namespace?

No. In your second example, when the compiler sees the definition of `N3` inside `N2`, the lookup of `N3` finds the `N3` that was declared outside `N2`, but that `N3` was not "introduced in the namespace in which the named-namespace-definition appears" (since it's not inside `N2`), or "introduced in a member of the inline namespace set of that namespace" since the inline namespace set of `N2` is the set of transitively inline namespaces *inside* `N2`. Thus, this new definition of `N3` doesn't extend the previous one.

> May a namespace be defined in an inline namespace and then be extended in its enclosing namespace?

Yes. In your first example, `N3` when looked up finds `N2::N3` which was "introduced in a member of the inline namespace set" since `N2` is part of the inline namespace set of `N1`.

We can understand the rationale for this apparent asymmetry as follows: in the second example, when `N3` is initially defined, it's being defined as a member of `N1` and *not* a member of any inline namespace of `N1`. Later, when `N2::N3` is being defined, if it were to extend `N1::N3`, it would be **retroactively** making `N3` a member of `N2`, which goes against common sense and is therefore disallowed. In the first example, `N3` is initially defined as a member of the inline namespace `N2` and there is no issue with extending it with the second definition later. (Though I cannot see an obvious reason why this is useful.)

Comment: It could be said simpler: members of the set of inline namespaces are members of the enclosing namespace. Could'n it be?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow See http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.def-7

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to rewrite the standard wording in a less dense (but possibly less precise) way:

1. We are lexically inside namespace `X`.
2. We encounter something that looks like `namespace Y { ... }`.
3. We look up `Y`. If `Y` is not a namespace name, move on<sup>1</sup>.
4. Was `Y` introduced (directly) in `X`? If so, move to point 6.
5. Was `Y` introduced in a namespace that is part of the inline set<sup>2</sup> of namespaces of `X`? If yes, move to 6. If not, move on<sup>1</sup>.
6. `Y` does extend the namespace we found in step 3.

<sup><sup>1</sup> *"Move on"* in the sense of *"ignore the cited standard paragraph"*.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> [The inline namespace set of N is the transitive closure of all inline namespaces in N.](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.def-8.sentence-2)</sup>

> may a namespace be defined in a namespace and then extended in one of its inline namespace?

No. We only consider the directly enclosing namespace (`N3` is extended in `N1` in your first example, and in `N2` in your second one) and its inline namespaces. This is why your second example does not work: `N2` (or its inline set of namespaces) does not contain any previous definition of `N3`.

> May a namespace be defined in an inline namespace and then be extended in its enclosing namespace?

Yes.

The examples you show are consistent with the standard wording.

Comment: It could be said simpler: members of the set of inline namespaces are members of the enclosing namespace. Could'n it be?